# UIWebView In A Custom TableView Cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a simple Interface Builder file that is a Custom TableView Cell. The custom tableview cell has two outlets...

1. WebView
2. Text Label

For some weird reason I get this error...

```
2012-07-12 16:28:23.206 VideoPush[3761:707] -[UITableViewCell webView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x168cc0
2012-07-12 16:28:23.211 VideoPush[3761:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell webView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x168cc0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x355e188f 0x37988259 0x355e4a9b 0x355e3915 0x3553e650 0x87279 0x33075efb 0x33074fd9 0x33074763 0x33018f37 0x355401fb 0x32410aa5 0x324106bd 0x32414843 0x3241457f 0x3243c911 0x3243c8e3 0x3305a10f 0x33047b33 0x33015ac3 0x33015567 0x33014f3b 0x371d422b 0x355b5523 0x355b54c5 0x355b4313 0x355374a5 0x3553736d 0x3304686b 0x33043cd5 0x86e5b 0x86e00)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

**MY XIB**

[image]

And here is **CustomCell.h** the controller of xib above...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface VPCustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;

@end
```

Last is my view controller that contains the actual table view...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    NSString *htmlString = @"<html><head> <meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 120\"/></head> <body style=\"background:#FFF;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\"> <div><object width=\"120\" height=\"80\"> <param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/1Xqn5IHbusA&f=gdata_videos&c=ytapi-my-clientID&d=nGF83uyVrg8eD4rfEkk22mDOl3qUImVMV6ramM\"></param> <param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param> <embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/1Xqn5IHbusA&f=gdata_videos&c=ytapi-my-clientID&d=nGF83uyVrg8eD4rfEkk22mDOl3qUImVMV6ramM\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"120\" height=\"80\"></embed> </object></div></body></html>";
    // Configure the cell...
    [cell.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com"]];
    cell.titleLabel.text = @"Hello";

    return cell;
}
```

Note: In the interface file I declare this and import my custom cell...

```
VPCustomCell *cell;
```

*What I have trouble understanding is the error what is the problem?*

Comment: you don't have a declaration for `cell` anywhere.  Are you using xibs, or storyboards?

Comment: storyboard for the tableview and xib for the custom cell

Comment: You can implement custom cells within the storyboard, this will be a much easier way to go, and it will also allow you to use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.  All you need to do is set your tableview to use prototype content, and then the cell that is displayed there you can change to your custom cell class, and insert the webview there

Comment: that works too, but why won't the way I'm trying to do work?

Comment: Where do you alloc the TableViewCell?

Comment: When you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` it is overriding the load you do in viewdidload.  If you want to use the xib, you will have to allocate it from the xib every time you load a cell

Comment: @TheMan  Is there any particular reason you wish to use a separate xib for the cell?  There really isn't any reason to use a separate xib for anything if you're using storyboards at all

Comment: Can you guys put an answer down for what you are talking about...  I don't think I understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Interface Builder, look in the Identity Inspector (option-command-3) and make sure that you have set the class of your table vie cell to to your `CustomCell` cell class.

Answer (score -3):

When working with UITableViewCells, it is better to deal with Tags rather than outlets.  For your issue, I would delete the outlets, give the Webview a Tag in the attribute inspector or whatever you want, say 100.  Do the same for the label.  Then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

NSString *htmlString = @"<html><head> <meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 120\"/></head> <body style=\"background:#FFF;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\"> <div><object width=\"120\" height=\"80\"> <param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/1Xqn5IHbusA&f=gdata_videos&c=ytapi-my-clientID&d=nGF83uyVrg8eD4rfEkk22mDOl3qUImVMV6ramM\"></param> <param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param> <embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/1Xqn5IHbusA&f=gdata_videos&c=ytapi-my-clientID&d=nGF83uyVrg8eD4rfEkk22mDOl3qUImVMV6ramM\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"120\" height=\"80\"></embed> </object></div></body></html>";
// Configure the cell...
UIWebView *thisWebView = (UIWebView*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
UILabel *thisLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:whateverYouWant];
[thisWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com"]];
thisLabel.text = @"Hello";
return cell;
```

And you should be good

Comment: The problem is more likely that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is returning a default `UITableViewCell` instead of the custom subclass

Comment: Personally I would never do this, as using tags in code makes it very messy and hard to read. However if you do want to do this, at least use constants for the tags as it will make the code more legible.